# unit test case for handler in ng-change in file input angularjs

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I used a directive to add a listener function on input file change, I'm going to create a unit test case for this in jasmine, but I'm not able to trigger function in unit case.

unit test code:

```
describe('customOnChange', function () {
beforeEach(module('app'));
beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope, $compile, $parse) {
    this.$rootScope = $rootScope;
    this.compile = $compile;
    this.parse = $parse;

    this.initDirective = function (config) {
        this.scope = this.$rootScope.$new();
        this.scope.listnerFunction = function($event){
            console.log("event called : ",$event);
        };
        this.element = angular.element('<input type="text" name="textField" id="textField" dynamic-data-editor-custom-on-change="listnerFunction($event)" ng-model="testText"/>');
        this.compile(this.element)(this.scope);
        this.$rootScope.$digest();
        $('body').append(this.element);
        this.$rootScope.$digest();
    };
}));

fit('Applied directive successfully', function() {
    this.initDirective();
    spyOn(this.scope,'listnerFunction');
    var ele =  this.element.find("input#textField").eq(0);
    console.log('element', ele);
    ele.triggerHandler('change');
    this.$rootScope.$apply();
    expect(this.scope.listnerFunction).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
});
```

The main directive code:

```
function () {
    'use strict';
    angular.module('app')
        .directive('customOnChange', function ($parse) {
            return {
                restrict: 'A',
                link: function ($scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
                    var attrHandler = $parse(attrs.dynamicDataEditorCustomOnChange);
                    var handler = function (e) {
                        $scope.$apply(function () {
                            attrHandler($scope, { $event: e });
                        });
                    };
                    element[0].addEventListener('change', handler, false);
                }
            };
        });
})();
```

I got the error on running test
 **Expected spy listnerFunction to have been called.**

Please help me to resolve the test case for the directive.

Comment: Where is the "listnerFunction" getting called in the directive?
Are you trying to spyOn the "handler" function?

Comment: @Sree.Bh listenerFunction should get called when the element gets changed, yes I want to spyOn handler function in the unit test case, because to verify that has been called when input element's change event happen.

Comment: @Sree.Bh in less word, I just want full unit test coverage of that directive.

Answer (score 0):

In your test the problem is: spy is created after the method `listnerFunction` function is called, so you see the error.

You should replace:

```
    this.scope.listnerFunction = function($event){
        console.log("event called : ",$event);
    };
```

with (`andCallFake` for `jasmine < 2`)

```
    this.scope.listnerFunction = 
    jasmine.createSpy("listnerFunction")
    .and.callfake(function($event){ 
        console.log("event called : ",$event);
    });
```

Comment: On trying as you suggested
`this.scope.listnerFunction = 
jasmine.createSpy("listnerFunction")
    .and.callfake(function($event){
        console.log("event called : ",$event);
    }); `



 I got the error like below


        
`TypeError: jasmine.createSpy(...).and.callfake is not a function`

Comment: The same solution works for me. Which version of jasmine are you using? For jasmine version <2...it is [andCallFake](https://jasmine.github.io/1.3/introduction#section-Spies:_%3Ccode%3EandCallFake%3C/code%3E)

Comment: I'm using version **"jasmine-core": "3.2.1"**

Sorry that I writeout wrong function name .and.callfake should be .and.callFake, but on correcting the function name still I'm facing.

**Expected spy listnerFunction to have been called.**

Comment: before the **expect** statement can you replace `$apply` with `$digest()` and try. Also try to run the test in debug mode.

Comment: I also tried the $digest as well but still, the same issue appears, I'm using headless mode for running test case, it could be the reason behind my test case failure?